# Why using classes?

Tags: python, class

I converted this "non-object-oriented" code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

redbutton = Button(frame, text="Red", fg="red")
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

bluebutton = Button(frame, text="Blue", fg="blue")
bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )

root.mainloop()
```

to this object-oriented code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
       Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.pack()

       widget=Button(self,text="Red", fg = "red")
       widget.pack(side = LEFT)

       widget = Button(self, text ="Blue", fg = "blue")
       widget.pack(side = RIGHT)
if __name__== '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

Both the snippets pop up a simple window on the screen. My question is, what are the benefits of objected-oriented programming (i.e. the use of classes) in this case?

If I want to generate 3 other windows (using classes), but with altered button colors, would I have to modify the blueprint (i.e. the class) or is there any way of doing it when I call a class instance?

Comment: It's much easier to read and understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's more reusable in the future and you're able to reference the objects within the class in a more comprehensible manner should you utilise it outside this module.

Comment: Really? Because as a non-py user, I understand every line in the first example and only most of the second. (what is `__name__=='__main__'`? If `Frame` is a `Window`, why can we call `Mainloop` on `Window()`?) I know these things, but my point is that calling simplicity the goal of OOP is really selling OOP short.

Comment: You could write the second example without the `__name__ == '__main__'` guard. And you could also do `root = Window(); root.mainloop()`

Comment: @Dan The `__main__` thing is a way of ensuring your code only executes if it is run if it's passed as the start script to the interpreter (as opposed to being imported from another module); it really should be in both scripts. That said, in simple cases, I agree with you about maintainability. From my own reading and thinking, I've started to come to the conclusion that OOP is at its best when you're using it for complex state management. I suspect that there is more to what the OP is trying to accomplish and that his back end code would benefit much more from OOP than what we see here.

Comment: Questions about "why" fit better on programmers.SE.

Comment: You've made a little mistake in your OOP code - you've created a red button but called it `widget`, then you created a blue button, and also called it `widget`, so you no longer have access to the red button object.  Also, you only created them in the local function namespace.  You should create them with `self.redbutton = Button(self, ...)` and `self.bluebutton = Button(self, ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what would happen if you had two windows both with redbutton and bluebutton. Can you see why it might help to encapsulate them inside an object?

Comment: If I was to create another window, I guess I would have to add another line `Window().mainloop()` at the objected-oriented case whilst for the other case, I would have to write the whole code again.Right?

Comment: Correct, or write a function that returned another window object.

Comment: @aychedee It seems to me that a function is not "OO" per se, and yet you're saying it provides the same benefit that you suggest OO does. So to me, it seems this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm giving you the different options. I'm not suggesting that writing a function is the correct way to do it. Or would make your code better.

Answer (score 4):

"Object-oriented programming" is more than just writing a procedural program using the `class` keyword. It's not OOP when you have one class, that's called only once, and that class has one method, which is `__init__()`. "In this case" there is no benefit, and you aren't really doing "object oriented programming".

The benefits of OOP - done properly - in general are well-known, but in my view the main one is reducing code complexity.

Comment: Exactly. OOP is a tool in your toolbox. You can't throw it at every problem and expect things to magically improve without knowing what it's good for. It's not appropriate for all problems, like just about everything else in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Following might be a use-case of a class structure

```
from Tkinter import *
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
       Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.pack()

    def createButton(self, text, fg, side):
        widget = Button(self, text = text, fg = fg)
        widget.pack(side = side)

if __name__== '__main__':
    _win = Window()
    _win.createButton("Red", "red", LEFT)
    _win.createButton("Blue", "blue", RIGHT)
    _win.mainloop()
```

But that is a simple and short code. For long and complex codes, it helps you to define class variables and reach them from any function within the class. Also you may create re-usable functions and you rid of repeated lines like in your example.

It is better to read more about OOP since it is not simple to tell all the aspects in here.